# How do I parse URL params after a hash with Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, foursquare, angularjs-routing

I'm trying to parse for the access_token from Foursquare where the URL is like this:

https://mywebsite.com/4sqredirect/#access_token=1234567890XXXXX

I've tried $routeParams and $location and get nothing returned.  Only after I tried $route, I did get an object back with the following attribute in it:

```
current:  { 
    params:  {  } 
    pathParams:  {  } 
    loadedTemplateUrl: partials/4sqredirect
    locals:  {  } 
    scope:  { 
        this:  { 
            $ref: $["current"]["scope"]
        } 
        route:  { 
            $ref: $
        } 
        location:  {  } 
        token: null
    }
}
```

Does this mean there's no way to get it using native AngularJS functions cause of the hash?

UPDATE:

my controller looks like as follows:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('4sqredirectCtrl', function ($scope, $route, $location, $routeParams) {
        $scope.route = $route;
        $scope.location = $location;
        $scope.token = $routeParams.access_token;
    });
```

my main js looks like as follows:

```
angular.module('myApp', [
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngRoute'
])
.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/main',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
    })
    .when('/4sqredirect/', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/4sqredirect',
        controller: '4sqredirectCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

From [angular location service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$location) `$location.hash()` method return `#after-hash`

so if your url is look like

```
https://mywebsite.com/4sqredirect/#access_token=1234567890XXXXX
```

then

`$location.hash()` return `access_token=1234567890XXXXX`

you need to split it `split('=')[1]`

see this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4tVZCuCIkqPzhvoa7ffN?p=preview) when you click `4Square` then `$location.url()` return

```
/4sqredirect/#access_token=123456
$location.hash().split('=')[1]
```

return `123456`

Comment: This worked great.  What was the major part of my problem is a stupid error on my part.  I was trying to use $location or $location.hash by themselves and not calling them.. eg.  $location.hash().  Yet, while $location.hash() worked, $location.search() still returned nothing...  Nevertheless, my question seemed answered by this.

Comment: Calling `$location.hash()` returns everything after the hash, but not the hash itself. In your provided example, it would return `after-hash`, not `#after-hash`.

Comment: $location wasn't defined for me, but window.location.hash.split did the trick!

Comment: This works better than split, when available and needed...  `var searchParams = new URLSearchParams($location.hash())`.  Then you can use, `searchParams.get('access_token')`.  Ref: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams).

Answer (score 9):

Use `$location.search()`

```
//e.g. url https://www.example.com/#!?name=123
var s = $location.search();
// {name: '123'}
```

> http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$location
>
> ### Search:
>
> Returns search part (as object) of current url when called without any parameter.

Comment: This didn't work.  $location.search returned nothing.  perhaps since the URL doesn't have a '?', it doesn't parse it?

Comment: Of course, if it doesn't have it then it's not a search. Add '?'

Comment: Unfortunately I can't add a ? since that part is predefined and returned to me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a "native angular" way to do it, but you do have access to the hash via `location.hash` as a string type. it's probably not ideal, but it's workable.

Comment: Location is also null so I don't even have a location.hash.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but `location` should always reflect the browser's current location. What are you attempting to do with the access token? and, is it being returned after the hash by 4sq or by you? I would have assumed it came as a query string parameter.

Comment: It's returned by 4sq.   https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth    "If a user accepts, they will be redirected back to
http://YOUR_REGISTERED_REDIRECT_URI/#access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN"

Answer (score 0):

There is in fact no direct support from Angular JS to do this. I wouldn't use `ngRoute`, because it already might expect the `#` at a different place. A simple solution to your problem is to use the `location.hash` and the `substring()` function:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.6/angular.js"></script>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script>
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window) {
  $scope.accessToken = $window.location.hash.substring(14);
}]);
</script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
<h1>Access Token</h1>
<p>{{accessToken}}</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You and Reza had somewhat the same idea that worked.  I liked Reza's more as it used the $location service rather than then the $window service.