# Best way to get all URL parameters in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I got this URL into my system:

```
http://localhost/myapp/#/campaign/confirm/edit/:id
```

What are the best ways to get `campaign`, `confirm` and `edit`inside my controller?

Comment: Will `campaign`, `confirm` and `edit` be parameters that can change?  Such as, will `confirm` actually contain some value like `Y` or `N` that you're trying to capture?

Comment: No. `campaign`, `confirm` and `edit` doesn't change. `:id` do.

Comment: Are you using ngRoute?  You shouldn't have to parse that at all.  You will assign anything matching /campaign/confirm/edit/:id to a specific controller.  At that point, the :id value is all you need to get.  The tutorial discusses routing, a good place to start if you're new to it.  https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've got this url formatted as an angular state (awesome!).
In this case, you can access $stateParams in your controller.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#stateparams-service

That should have the information you need, assuming your state is something like this. This example makes all 4 parts into accessible variables, that's if you really do need ALL parts of that path. It's probably worth putting in some non-variable data in there, otherwise it might get a little difficult to separate this state from others that are formed in a similar way:

```
$stateProvider.state('myStateName', {
  url: '{campaign}/{confirm}/{edit}/{id}'
});
```

---

```
myModule.controller('fooCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams){
  console.log(
    $stateParams.campaign,
    $stateParams.confirm,
    $stateParams.edit,
    $stateParams.id);
});
```

Comment: They only tell me how to get the `:id`, not the path.

Comment: Get the full state name with: $state.current.name

Comment: Although that's not what I asked for, it can solve my problem, @HankScorpio. This way I can create an `init()` function and verify if `$state.current.name == 'campaignEditConfirm'`. Thanks for information.

Comment: It isn't? You've now got a way to get your state parameters and your full state name.
What's missing?

Comment: I wanted to get route params that aren't variables without split URL by `/`, if possible.

Comment: Ah ok. For future reference a "parameter" is a kind of variable.

Comment: I see. My title is wrong. Actually, looking here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878335/how-do-i-parse-url-params-after-a-hash-with-angularjs they suggest to split `$location.hash()` string. That's what I want to avoid.